# How to show Keyboard?

Tags: flutter, keyboard, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I ask you a question regarding Flutter UI.

I want to show keyboard in ios simulator, but I cannot see.

Could you tell me how to show keyboard in ios simulator?

child: Column(

```
        children: [

          TextFormField(
            autofocus: true,
            textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,

             decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'タイトル',
               ),
               validator: (String value) {
                    if (value.trim().isEmpty) {
                     return 'タイトル is required';
                    }
                 },
             ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to toggle the software keyboard (the one on your simulator) by pressing `cmd + k`. This is assuming that your TextFormField is working properly. That's something that took me a long time to learn.

Answer (score 0):

You could add keyboard parameter to specify the keyboard type but without it also it should show the keyboard when you click on the textfield

Comment: Please modify your answer. Add this, You can now inside your app specify a custom ```TextInputAction```. This won't break existing ```TextField```. It just adds the ability to override the default behavior. Code: ```new TextField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
  textInputAction: TextInputAction.newline,
),```

Answer (score 0):

You need to go settings in the Xcode IDE and look the option ¨I/O¨ there is an option call Toggle Software Keyboard